# Typescript tsconfig trouble finding modules and names

Tags: typescript, compilation, tsc, tsconfig

My project structure:

```
root
├── project1
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── index.ts
├── project2
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

I'm using the default tsconfig and I would expect it to resolve modules correctly, but Im getting errors like:

```
Cannot find module 'path'
Cannot find name 'require'
```

It works if I compile with 2 different tsconfig in each projects. Why is this not working properly? What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the TypeScript compiler is looking for a sibling node_modules folder to the tsconfig.json file. Is it possible for you to create a package.json in the root of the project as well and in the root install the @types/ files that it is looking for?

Comment: I could do that but each project can have its own different @types. I'd like to keep considering them as 2 separate projects but be able to compile both at the same time from the root.

Comment: I don't see a problem mixing the @types in the root package.json as this is only for compilation and tooling - unless they have different versions of the same types files?

Comment: Have you thought about using Lerna to manage the projects? https://lerna.js.org/

Comment: https://medium.com/@NiGhTTraX/how-to-set-up-a-typescript-monorepo-with-lerna-c6acda7d4559